# Linked workbooks not updating formatting

Tags: excel, hyperlink, formatting

Any time my workbook updates from the master workbook, it messes up the formatting. This is because I have either added or removed a row. Is there anyway to fix this? Or to make the formatting move with the cells?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is don't use linked workbooks. I *never* use them...they are simply too dangerous for reasons such as this. Either keep everything in one workbook, or look at using Excels new PowerQuery aka "Get and Transform" functionality to bring data in from your master workbook. (This functionality is baked in to Excel 2016, and available as a free add-in for other versions. Give Google a spin for more info)